# Javascript matching game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to write code for matching memory game for kids where we flip tiles to match 1 to 'one' or 1 to any image which has one item and 2 for 2 items.
I wrote for 1 matches to 1 but I am not able to match number with a word or image. Can somebody help me the code?
Below is the code I am working on:-

```
var memory_array =         ['1','one','2','two','3','three','4','four','5','five','6','six','7','seven','8','eight','9','nine'];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;
Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function(){
var i = this.length, j, temp;
while(--i > 0){
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    temp = this[j];
    this[j] = this[i];
    this[i] = temp;
}
}
function newBoard(){
tiles_flipped = 0;
var output = '';
memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++){
    output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'"              onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_array[i]+'\')"></div>';
}
    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
}
function memoryFlipTile(tile,val){
if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2){
    tile.style.background = '#FFF';
    tile.innerHTML = val;
    if(memory_values.length == 0){
        memory_values.push(val);
        memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
    } else if(memory_values.length == 1){
        memory_values.push(val);
        memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]){
            tiles_flipped += 2;
            // Clear both arrays
            memory_values = [];
            memory_tile_ids = [];
            // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
            if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length){
                alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
                document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                newBoard();
            }
```

All the tiles remain flipped and it doesn't match.

Comment: This would be easier with a plnkr or codepen example to see what happens.

Comment: You might be better served with 2 objects (think dictionaries) where you can have and id and the word and then match off of the ids.  I agree with the comment above, this would be better with a fiddle or an example somewhere.